# How can I get a `Single<T>` from an infinite sequence?

Tags: swift, macos, rx-swift

### Problem

Given an `Observable<NaturalNumber>` that represent the sequence off all natural numbers.

**Example 1** *(addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47310364/418543), check next example)*

How can I get a `Single<String>` that contains the sum expression and result of all the numbers between a range?
Ex: for a range from 10 to 13 -> "11 + 12 = 23"

So far this is what I have (and don't like):

```
let min = 10
let max = 15
//No special meaning, just to add an "error" case
let maxAllowed = 20

Single<String>.create(subscribe: { (complete) -> Disposable in
    return Observable.range(start: 0, count: Int.max)
        .filter { min < $0 && max > $0 }
        .scan([], accumulator: { (acc: [Int], number) in
            guard number < maxAllowed else {
                complete(.error(SomeError()))
                return []
            }
            return acc + [number]
        })
        .single { $0.count == (max - min - 1) }
        .map { range in
            let sum = range.reduce(0, +)
            return range.reduce("", { (acc, number) -> String in
                if number == (max - 1) {
                    return acc + " + \(number) = \(sum)"
                } else {
                    return acc + "\(acc != "" ? " + " : "")\(number)"
                }
        })}
        .subscribe(onNext: { complete(.success($0)) })
}).subscribe(onSuccess: { (s) in
    print("Success: \(s)") // "Success: 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 = 50"
}, onError: { (e) in
    print("Error")
}).disposed(by: d)
```

**Example 2**

Given a `struct Point3D` that needs to be constructed from an array of size 3. How can I get a `Single<Point3D>` where the values in the input vector should be in a specified range?

```
let min = 10
let max = 15
//No special meaning, just to add an "error" case
let maxAllowed = 20

struct Point3D {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
    let z: Int

    init(vector: [Int]) {
        x = vector[0]
        y = vector[1]
        z = vector[2]
    }
}

Single<Point3D>.create(subscribe: { (complete) -> Disposable in
    return Observable.range(start: 0, count: Int.max)
        .filter { min < $0 && max > $0 }
        .scan([], accumulator: { (acc: [Int], number) in
            guard number < maxAllowed else {
                complete(.error(SomeError()))
                return []
            }
            return acc + [number]
        })
        .single { $0.count == 3 }
        .map(Point3D.init(vector:))
        .subscribe(onNext: { complete(.success($0)) })
}).subscribe(onSuccess: { (s) in
    print("Success: \(s)") // "Success: Point3D #1(x: 11, y: 12, z: 13)"
}, onError: { (e) in
    print("Error")
}).disposed(by: d)
```

*Keep in mind:*
This is an abstraction of a real problem I have that involves an infinite sequence of values coming from a bluetooth connection. So please try to avoid answers that change to problem instead of the solution unless you think it make sense given the above.

### Objective

The patter I look to extract is: select some values from an infinite sequence and construct a new one with only those values. Once all the values are collected completes with `.success(allValues)`

What I want to improve over the examples is:

- The need of the `Single<T>.create()` wrapper. It's there only for been able to complete with and error in some cases (the `maxAlloed` in the examples). Also I'm not sure if the `asSingle()` operator completes the returned `Single` after a value is returned (?).
- The use of `filter`, `scan` and `single` to take values from the original sequence and to control when the finite sequence should complete. Think on the *Example 2*.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what about this code you don't like? I agree it's hard to read, but that's easily fixed by splitting it up rather than doing everything inline. I will note that using `scan` to build an array this way is incredibly inefficient (it generates a lot of copying), but if the arrays aren't very long, then that may not matter as much as keeping the code simple (they're only 3 elements here, so that's not too bad). What kind of improvements are you looking for, though?

Comment: @RobNapier I add a more specific description of what I think should be improved in the examples. Thanks for the questions! I really enjoy this :D

Comment: Do you mean `Signal` or `Single`? Sometimes you're using one and sometimes the other (and sometimes `Signle`). I think you mean `Single` everywhere.

Comment: Your new example is very surprising. Are you saying that if the acceptable range is 1...10 with maxAllowed of 200, the stream `1,2,100,3` should be `Point(x: 1, y: 2, z: 3)` and the stream `1,2,250,3` should be an error? That seems a really strange way to extract a structure from a stream. I think some input streams and expected outputs is going to help think through this best.

Comment: For range: 1...10, and maxAllowed: 200 stream that pass the `single` operator will always be `1,2,3`. For the same range and maxAllowed: 2 `Single` completes with an error and no further processing is done. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the problem correctly (reduce a continuous portion of an infinite sequence to a `Single`), I would compose the following:

- Skip elements until the start
- Take elements until the end
- Reduce
- Convert to Single

In code for summing (but the same should be true for any infinite sequence, even of bluetooth events):

```
let sum = Observable.range(start: 0, count: Int.max)
    .skipWhile({ $0 <= min })
    .takeWhile({ $0 < max })
    .reduce(0, accumulator: +)
    .asSingle()

// Can't have any errors in the above code, but to demonstrate the general case
sum.subscribe(onSuccess: { print($0) },
              onError: { (e) in print("Error: \(e)") })
    .disposed(by: d)
```

I wasn't quite clear what `maxAllowed` was doing in your original code (which may be the complexity), but if the point is to throw errors if a value is out of range, then you'd just throw in the `reduce` accumulator. Or you could add an identity `map` in the middle that just looked for invalid values and threw errors in those cases.

Comment: Sorry but I think it's not appropriate (or polite) to say that an answer is too simple, even though it is really simple

Comment: My goal was the opposite; I don't want be insulting with a simplistic answer to what feels like it's a more complicated question when the OP seems to have a solid understanding of Rx. But it's a fair criticism, so I'll modify it to try to be clearer. Thank you.

Comment: Hm. You find a hole in my example... This answer is totally fine given the case of the question, but is not quite I need. Imagine that the predicate in `takeWhile` needs to take a transformation of the values. (Meanwhile I update the example)

Comment: Thanks; it would helpful to know what you expect the above to output. For me, it just prints `Error` since it encounters values greater than `maxAllowed`.